# change color of prompt in bash profile

Tags: bash, terminal, iterm

I am trying to change the color of the prompt in my terminal to green text for the user at the start and white `~`

Currently my .bash_profile file is configured the following way to provide a yellow color for the user name and a pink color for the `~`

```
PS1='\e[33;1m\u@\h: \e[31m\W\e[0m\$'
```

Does anyone know how to modify the above to change to the colors to green and white?

Comment: Which shell, `bash` or `zsh`?

Comment: I am using Bash `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
PS1='\e[32;1m\u@\h: \e[37m\W\e[0m\$'
```

The numbers after the `[` are the color codes. [See this reference](http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html).

Comment: Unreal! Legend, thanks! can accept the answer in 2 mins

Comment: do you know who to put a space between the name of the folder and the dollar sign? currently it looks like this `directory$ touch index.html`

Comment: `PS1='\e[32;1m\u@\h: \e[37m\W\e[0m \$'` should result in `directory $`. (Keep the slash and dollar sign together.)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to change the [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), specifically the [colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).

`\e[...m` takes a semicolon-separate list of codes to manipulate how the following text is displayed. `33` represents yellow foreground text, `1` represents bold text, `31` represents red foreground text, and 0 resets all values (foreground and background colors, styles, etc) to their terminal defaults.

```
# Make text yellow and bold, then make it red (keeping it bold)
# and finally restore the default
PS1='\e[33;1m\u@\h: \e[31m\W\e[0m\$'
```

To use green/white instead of yellow/red, change 33 to 32 and 31 to 37. Also, be sure to enclose characters that do not take up any space on screen inside `\[...\]` so that the shell can properly determine the length of your prompt.

```
PS1='\[\e[32;1m\]\u@\h: \[\e[37m\]\W\[\e[0m\]\$'
```

This assumes that your terminal understands ANSI escape sequences; a more portable method is to use `tput` to output the codes your actual terminal uses:

```
PS1='\[$(tput bold; tput setaf 2)\u@\h: \[$(tput setaf y)\]\W$(tput sgr0)\$ '
```

---

`zsh`, incidentally, makes this much easier; it has built-in escapes for changing the color in a terminal-independent way:

```
# 1. Everything between %B and %b is in bold
# 2. Everything between %F{x} and %f is in a different color;
#    x can be a color name, and you can switch from one
#    color to another without using %f
# 3. zsh is smart enough to account for built-in escapes when
#    computing the prompt lenght, so no equivalent of \[...\]
#    is needed
# 4. %n is the same as \u
# 5. %m is the same as \h
# 6. %~ is roughly the same as \W
# 7. %# is roughly the same as \$
PS1='%B%F{green}%n@%m: %F{white}%~%b%f%# '
```

Comment: thanks @chepner! gave you the up vote but already gave the green tick! thanks for your help tho

Comment: You can change answers if you like (not saying you need to, though).

Answer (score 0):

This approach has two benefits over the others:

1. it brackets the escape sequences using `\[` and ``]`to prevent character count problems with`CTRL-A` editing of wrapped lines
2. it uses `tput` to change the colors so that it is a little more self-documenting what is being done:

   `PS1='\[$(tput setaf 2)\]\u@\h: \[$(tput setaf 7)\]\W\[$(tput sgr0)\]\$'`

Answer (score 0):

To change color of prompt in each section, try to use this simple repo:

https://github.com/joenmarz/bashrc-alias

You can change the color of each prompt section like:

- username
- '@' sign
- hostname
- time
- bracket sign '[' and ']'
- root indicator (# for root user), ($ for non-root user)

The look of your prompt will be like:

> [username@hostname 00:00 AM ~/working/directory $]

Go to line 33 of this file **(bashrc-alias/.bashrc)** to customize each prompt section color variables:

- **open_brk_color**     to change *open bracket* color
- **closed_brk_color**     to change *closed bracket* color
- **at_color**     to change *'@' sign* color
- **username_color**     to change *username* color
- **hostname_color**     to change *hostname* color
- **time_color**     to change *time prompt* color
- **wd_color**     to change *working directory prompt* color
- **ri_color**     to change *root indicator* color

## How To Install

1. Clone this repository at your home directory
   `git clone https://github.com/joenmarz/bashrc-alias`
2. Add the file path inside your existing ~/.bash file:
   `. /home/$USER/bashrc-alias/aliases`
3. refesh your .bashrc source by typing:
   `source ~/.bashrc`

I made it easier by adding some variables to each prompt section.